# List of locationmode to use with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I need to make a graphical representation of data distributed in Brazil, which is my country.

I found that `plotly` can do this job, but when I went to research how to use plotly, every tutorial was using the `locationmode` attribute as 'USA-states'.

Is there a list with countries codes, so I can go after to see which is the right way of calling it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From docs: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scattergeo-locationmode

```
locationmode ( enumerated : "ISO-3" | "USA-states" | "country names" ) 
default: "ISO-3" 
Determines the set of locations used to match entries in `locations` to regions on the map.
```

So for Brazil you have to add these lines:

```
locations = ["Brazil"],
locationmode = 'country names'
```

Comment: But what if I need to set values to each state in Brazil?

Comment: Well... then that is currently not supported. See this issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1354